# Use a variable calculated average of a specific field in the Title band

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a variable which stores the calculated average of a specific field.

Is there any way to use this variable in the *Title* band? When I try to do it, I just get **null** in the *Title* but the correct value in the *Column Footer*.

The only other possibility for this I see is, to precalculate it in Java and pass it as an argument, but I'm trying to avoid that.

I'm using *JasperReports* and *iReport* in version 3.7.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Variable* and the *Text Field* both have the property *Evaluation Time*. Set it to **Report** for both and it works.

Also look at http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=67697

Comment: Thanks, I just figured this out by myself but wasn't able to answer this by myself due to missing reputation (This was my first action on Stack Overflow).