# Using variables in Conditional Style

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a *Title* band with a *Text Field* containing a calculated *Variable* `$V{avg_perc}`. The *Text Field* has the **evaluationTime** set to **Report**, same for the *Variables* **resetType**. 
Now I'm trying to set the background color of this field with a *Conditional Style* but I keep getting an error message saying something like:

```
Invalid expression: !Double.isNaN($V{avg_perc}) && $V{avg_perc} >= 0.8
```

I'm doing exactly the same thing with the same *Conditional Style* in the *Column Footer* and it works without any problems, even if I set the **evaluationTime** for this field to **Report** too.

After removing `!Double.isNaN($V{avg_perc})` I don't get an error anymore but the expression still doesn't work. My field stays red which is the basic color when none of the conditions is valid, no matter which value `$V{avg_perc}` has. It still works in the *Column Footer*, though. This is my style:

```
<style name="avg_color" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FF0000" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{avg_perc} >= 0.8]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#008000"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{avg_perc} >= 0.6 && $V{avg_perc} < 0.8]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#FFCC00"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

Used Fields and Variables for this:

```
<field name="perc" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<variable name="avg_perc" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Average">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{perc}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Any idea how to get this thing to work? I'm using *JasperReports* and *iReport* in version 3.7.4.

Comment: What is your *iReport* settings of this properties: ***org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source***, ***org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance***, ***org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.TargetPlatform***?

Comment: Can you post the ***avg_perc*** variable definition? BTW, the expression `!Double.isNaN($F{avg_perc}) && $F{avg_perc} >= 0.8` works for me - I've changed variable on field.

Comment: I added the Field and Variable definitions to my question.

Comment: IMHO, the expression in ***conditionalStyle*** works like the value with ***evaluationTime*** equals **Now**. You can check this with simple test - you can add two *fields* with `<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$V{avg_perc}]]></textFieldExpression>` and different values (**Now** and **Report**) of ***evaluationTime*** property

Comment: Seems to be true for the _Title_ band. I tried setting **avg_perc** to a fix value of 0.9 with the **resetType** set to **None** and it worked, no matter which **evaluationTime** was set for the fields. Setting the **evaluationTime** of a field to **Now** with a calculated variable as value causes its output to be **null** (which was my issue in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259979/use-a-variable-calculated-average-of-a-specific-field-in-the-title-band) and its color to be red. I hope I can get this to work somehow, I don't really want to have to precalculate the avg in Java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally found the solution for my problem. Adding

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.evaluation.time.enabled" value="true"/>
```

at the report level causes a *Conditional Style* to be performed at the moment at which the element is evaluated.
See [this answer](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/526599/solved-conditional-style-evaluation-time#node-571861) in the Jaspersoft Community for more information.

Answer (score 3):

in your view ireport designer.

click on the field and in the properties panel.: markup = styled selected

Right click on the fied. edit expression:

```
($F{fila1}.equals("c") ? "<style forecolor='red'>"+ $F{fila1}+"</style>" : $F{fila1})
```

or xml

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{fila1}.equals("c") ? "<style forecolor='red'>"+ $F{fila1}+"</style>" : $F{fila1})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify this code based on your requirement

```
<style name="alternateStyle" fontName="Arial">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{AMOUNT}.intValue() == 0)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FF0000" isBold="true"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

And also refer this link : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359707/set-background-color-in-textfield-from-condition-using-ireport/44677150#44677150)