# Set background color in textfield from condition using iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a problem with conditionalStyle in *iReport*. I have the following *textFields* (*${nameField} = field value*):

${field1}=30       ${field2}=40          ${field3}=50 
${field4}=23          ${field5}=1           ${field6}=45 
${field7}=34          ${field8}=20     ${field9}=0

I need set difference background in every textField depend of the value of the field. I create a new Style and set the conditions:

```
<style name="ColoredField">
   <conditionalStyle>
     <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1} == 300]]></conditionExpression>
    <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FCFF00"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

As you can see, the Style use only `$F{field1}`, and I need make a dynamic style (or something), that apply to every *textField*.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not clear, can you be more explicit ?

1. From my understanding , each value will mean a specific background for a textfield, in that case your conditional style value should depend on variable. Maybe using Variables in your style can suit your need.
2. Add multiple conditional style under each style as below:

each textField can now have different background :

```
<style name="ColoredField">
   <conditionalStyle>
     <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1} == 100]]></conditionExpression>
    <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FCFFFF"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
     <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{fiCeld1} == 200]]></conditionExpression>
    <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#00FF00"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
     <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1} == 300]]></conditionExpression>
    <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FCFF00"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

Comment: Soulemane thanks for your answer, Ok. Efectly in your answer you add multiple conditions (3) in one style called ColoredField, but, if you look, that condition only apply to the field $F{field1}, and I need apply that style to every field: $F{field2}, $F{field3}, $F{field4}. But I don't want duplicate that code for every field.

Comment: One way to achieve that is if you consider a fixed value or a range of values for a given color. E.g 100 = green, 200= red, 200=yellow. Then replace the $F{field1} in the previous multiconditional style a variable say $V{varValueToBg}. With that you can apply the same style to differnt field, because whenever the value of the field will match a condition then that bgcolor with appear.

Comment: Soulemane, but how I could assign the value of every field to the variable (in your example variable $V{varValueToBg}). I can modify the style and add de conditional variale. But I don't find how assign the value of every field to the variable. (I'm sorry for my bad english), and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a direct way to accomplish this task - you have to create a separate style for each field.

Considering this you can concentrate your effort on creating a small script that replicate the XML with the same stile for the fields you have. Then you can just copy/paste the XML into the report source file. Each time you need to change the style you will have to go back to your XML generator.

Answer (score 0):

Try ths one :

```
<style name="myStyle" fontName="Arial">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{SANCTION_AMOUNT_MEASURE}.intValue() == 100)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#FF0000" isBold="true"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{SANCTION_AMOUNT_MEASURE}.intValue() == 200)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#00FF00" isBold="true"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{SANCTION_AMOUNT_MEASURE}.intValue() == 300)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="#0000FF" isBold="true"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```