# How to change to background color of textfield Dynamically in iReport using Java

Tags: java, ireport

I want to change the background color of my text field based on a variable.

Here's the logic:

```
if (variable <= 20) then
 text field color = red
else if (variable > 20) then
text field color = green
end if
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the way to do that its using a conditional style: You have to create a new style:

https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/825330/how-create-conditional-style-jaspersoft-studio

put the condition in the style and apply the style to your textfield.

Comment: Can you give a sample of what should be put on that conditional style?

Comment: I got it, but is it possible to put multiple conditional style in one text field?

Comment: You can put several conditions on your conditional style: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359707/set-background-color-in-textfield-from-condition-using-ireport, but as far i know you cannot put several styles in a field.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <style name="alternateStyle" fontName="Arial">
      <conditionalStyle>
         <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{SANCTION_AMOUNT_MEASURE}.intValue() <= 20)]]></conditionExpression>
         <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FF0000" isBold="true"/>
      </conditionalStyle>
      <conditionalStyle>
         <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{SANCTION_AMOUNT_MEASURE}.intValue() > 20)]]></conditionExpression>
         <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#00FF00" isBold="true"/>
      </conditionalStyle>
   </style>
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for your code example?

Comment: when you are work with the style with condition you have to must write you expression in the Boolean constructor.