# Jasper Conditional Style with parameter

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to set up style in my post but it does not work, I have a error :

```
 1. Parameter not found : choixImpression
```

But the problem is that I created the variable and it will be displayed if i add it in a textfield but the conditional style do not work.

My *jrxml*:

```
<jasperReport ...>
    <style name="Table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#2E6F98">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{choixImpression}.toString().equals("MODERNE_NOIR_ET_BLANC"))]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#99FF99"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <parameter name="choixImpression" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="choixImpression" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$P{choixImpression}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <title>
        <band height="198" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" x="201" y="63" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{field}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Try to add `<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.evaluation.time.enabled" value="true"/>` at report's header. The problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40273660/876298)

Comment: <textField>
    <reportElement x="299" y="174" width="100" height="15"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{choixImpression}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>

Comment: BTW, What is a reason to use parameter at variable expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using variables in Conditional Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269736/using-variables-in-conditional-style)

Comment: I still have the error, it does not change anything

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

You reference a **parameter** not a **variable**.

Use `$V{choixImpression}` instead of `$P{choixImpression}` if really a variable should be used.

### EDIT

You have a parenthesis problem...

Your code try to get a `Boolean` value of the `String`, and then this `Boolean` value is compared to the specified `String` constant:

```
<conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{choixImpression}.toString()).equals("MODERNE_NOIR_ET_BLANC")]]></conditionExpression>
```

Should try something like this:

```
<conditionExpression><![CDATA["MODERNE_NOIR_ET_BLANC".equals($P{choixImpression})]]></conditionExpression>
```

### EDIT

I do not know, but does the order of things count?

Your parameters are declared after the expression...

Comment: @dadadaa Additionally, if you are using version with autoboxing/unboxing Java support - you can remove Boolean wrapper

Comment: `Boolean.valueOf()` - It is not necessary (with autoboxing/unboxing)

Comment: `Your parameters are declared after the expression...` - it is ok for JR template

Comment: If I go back the parameters, the JRXML is invalid